# Angular - How to use $scope into $compile?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use my scope into a compile.... I want that every time I click on a button, a div is created with the round number in it.

```
main.controller('fightController', function($scope, $http, Services, $compile) {

    $scope.doAFight = function(playerHab, monsterHab) {
        Services.getFight(playerHab, monsterHab)
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.fight = data;
                $scope.round = 0;
            });
    };

    $scope.addRound = function() {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('boiteCombat')).append($compile("
            <div class=rondeCombat>
                <div class=numRonde> Ronde " + $scope.round + " </div>
            </div>
            ")($scope));
    };

});
```

it just gives me an error that what i'm trying to do is illegal...

Comment: it looks like you can much easily do it by pushing the round number in an array and show the array with an ng-repeat, have you tried that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to manipulate the data and let the view binding take effect, rather than manipulate the view on your own. Use an `ngRepeat` and add to an array for more rows:

```
$scope.rounds = []; //lets this be the array we iterate over

$scope.addRound = function() {
    $scope.rounds.push({round: $scope.round});
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="boiteCombat">
    <div class="rondeCombat" ng-repeat="round in rounds">
        <div class=numRonde> Ronde {{round.round}} </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!!